# Are questions about how English worked at a certain point on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

If I have a question about the history of English like “When did [some thing] become incorrect?” or “Was [some thing] different during [some time]?”, would that be off-topic?

Comment: Those seem fine to me. Plus, bonus, interesting.

Comment: Very relevant: [Are Old and Middle English on on topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2048/are-old-and-middle-english-questions-really-on-topic)

Comment: There are some of us here who love those types of questions. Although they may not garner much rep, they are usually interesting and fun, and make the site a better place.

Comment: @Cascabel Yeah, I've got a good one I'm going to ask soon and just wanted to make sure it was alright.

Comment: I look forward to it! Please make sure you do a little research first, especially on sites like Etymonline, which is considered General Reference here.

Comment: @Cascabel Dang, just realized it's a dupe of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10522/332980) as I did a little research lol

Comment: yepper...that's why we ask for a little research first, just to avoid that issue. That said, maybe there is a unique way you can phrase your Q to keep it on-topic...note that that Q is very old, and _still_ has no accepted answer.

Comment: lemme know if I can help in some way.

Comment: Questions that dig into the history of the English language and the origin of English terms are on-topic on ELU. Unfortunately users  tend to dislike this sort of questions, probably because  it is often difficult to give precise answers being the facts often lost in the mist of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, history of the language is very much on topic.

For example, [mentions of Old English](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?page=125&tab=Newest&q=old%20english) has ~6200 results, asked starting from the very inception of the site.

I don't think this is an exact duplicate but here's a meta question [Are Old and Middle English on on topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2048/are-old-and-middle-english-questions-really-on-topic)  (full disclosure: the main answer there is mine).